# Spring boot + spring data jpa: how do I know if adding data to table failed due to duplicate primary key?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-boot

I am using Spring boot and Spring data jpa to add data to a mysql database.

I code for controller class is like this,

```
@Controller
public class SomeController{

    @Autowired
    SomeRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping("/add")
    @ResponseBody
    public String add(){
        SomeClass someobject = new someClass();
        try{
            repository.save(someobject);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return  e.toString();
        }
        return "success";
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that if the data entry fails due to duplicate primary key, I still get success message. How would I know if data entry has failed?

Answer (score 0):

in order to know if primary key is already set in db you have to perform a get (repository.get(xxx))